# Keep discontiguous unequal sized data in same series of XY scatter plot in same series.

Tags: vba, excel

I need to have code that creates an XYscatterplot based off of areas of data that can be discontiguous, and may also be unequal sized.

For example, a user may select A6:A11 and D7:D20. I would like the macro to then create a graph using the first as X values, and the next as Y values.

I have found a strange solution to this:

```
Set r = Selection
Set r1 = r.Areas(1)
Set r2 = r.Areas(2)

    ActiveSheet.Range("A5:A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatter).Select
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = r1
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = r2
```

If the following line is deleted, then excel creates two series instead of just one.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("A5:A6").Select
```

It seems like this line shouldn't be required to do what I want, but it seems to provide some sort of initialization and prevents data from being split into two series. Is there another way, that would look more professional?

Thanks in advance!